# Reading custom sparse format in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read the following format and save it in a Dataframe.

```
0    21:1.00   42:1.00   63:1.00
0    9: .18   18: .82   32: .15   36: .62
1    8:1.00   22: .06
...
```

The format consists in:

- The first integer is the class of the sample (this is a classification dataset)
- The following are the attributes. So for instance, in the first row, `21:1.00` means that the attribute `21` has a value of 1.

The problem I'm facing is that this is a sparse representation of a dataset, and I want something like:

```
class attr0 attr1 attr2 ... attrn
 0      0     0     1   ...  3
```

A dense representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to split and expand the values into two columns and convert to `int` and `float`.

Then pivot so that the first column becomes the column headers, and the second becomes the values.

Then just cleanup the display by adding the attr_ prefix, and renaming the index column to class:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0: ["21:1.00", "42:1.00", "63:1.00", None],
                   1: ["9: .18", "18: .82", "32: .15", "36: .62"],
                   2: ["8:1.00", "22: .06", None, None]})

df = df.stack() \
    .str.split(':', expand=True) \
    .astype({0: int, 1: float}) \
    .droplevel(0) \
    .reset_index() \
    .pivot(index='index', columns=0, values=1) \
    .reset_index() \
    .add_prefix('attr') \
    .fillna(0) \
    .rename(columns={'attrindex': 'class'})

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
 class  attr8  attr9  attr18  attr21  attr22  attr32  attr36  attr42  attr63
     0    0.0   0.00    0.00     1.0    0.00    0.00    0.00     1.0     1.0
     1    0.0   0.18    0.82     0.0    0.00    0.15    0.62     0.0     0.0
     2    1.0   0.00    0.00     0.0    0.06    0.00    0.00     0.0     0.0
```

---

Expand into multiple columns

```py
df = df.stack() \
    .str.split(':', expand=True) \
    .astype({0: int, 1: float})

print(df.to_string())
```

```
        0     1
0 0  21.0  1.00
  1   9.0  0.18
  2   8.0  1.00
1 0  42.0  1.00
  1  18.0  0.82
  2  22.0  0.06
2 0  63.0  1.00
  1  32.0  0.15
3 1  36.0  0.62
```

---

Pivot into desired format

```py
df = df \
    .droplevel(0) \
    .reset_index() \
    .pivot(index='index', columns=0, values=1) \
    .reset_index()

print(df.to_string())
```

```
0  index    8     9    18   21    22    32    36   42   63
0      0  NaN   NaN   NaN  1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  1.0  1.0
1      1  NaN  0.18  0.82  NaN   NaN  0.15  0.62  NaN  NaN
2      2  1.0   NaN   NaN  NaN  0.06   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

Cleanup, rename, etc.

```py
df = df \
    .add_prefix('attr') \
    .fillna(0) \
    .rename(columns={'attrindex': 'class'})
```